# command not found using sudo in script

Tags: shell-script, command

I am trying to execute sudo command inside a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo node app.js
```

and it throws me :

```
sudo: node: command not found
```

If I try to execute only node app.js (without sudo ),it runs ok.

If I try to just run `sudo -h` , it prints the sudo help.

But , when I am trying the `sudo node app.js` it throws me the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like `node` is on a non-standard path, or at least not on root's path. There are a couple of ways around this.

1. Use the full path to `node`

   - Find the full path using `which node`
   - If say it's in `/home/user/bin/node` then call `sudo /home/user/bin/node app.js`
   - Or as @UlrichSchwarz suggested you can combine the two with command substitution: `sudo $(which node) app.js`
   - Remember the user you `sudo` to needs read/execute permissions on the location, not as much of an issue when you `sudo` to `root`

---

2. Call `sudo` with the `-E` option to preserve environment variables

   - `sudo -E node app.js`
   - This will keep your `$PATH` from before `sudo`
   - You can see the `sudo` manpage for more info: http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo

Comment: 1b: call `sudo $(which node) app.js` (which admittedly fails if there is no `node` in the user's path).

Comment: @Dave:If you use the `$(which node)` it works great!Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I threw it into the answer. Figured I'd keep the answer simple, but that is a good addition.