# Running a custom command with sudo doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I've made a custom command in bash and I placed it in `~/.local/bin` which is a path loaded by the `~/.profile`. When I run the command through a terminal without `sudo` it's fine, but when I try to run it with `sudo` the output is:

```
sudo: my_command: command not found
```

Could you tell me how I can accomplish that?

Comment: `sudo $(type -P my_command)`

Comment: Possibly related: [How to make `sudo` preserve $PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path) [command not found using sudo in script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292889/command-not-found-using-sudo-in-script)

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo -E`, this preserves your environment, may not work in all cases.
Seeing as you need an environment variable that is set by .profile also try `sudo -i` this performs a login, requiring you to also use `-c my_command`
If you still want to use `sudo my_command` without the any options check your /etc/sudoers file, and ensure the secure_path variable is set and contains the path that contains your command. This may require placing it somewhere generally available like `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` has a PATH that is different than yours. `sudo` does not read `~/.profile`.

Check it out:

```
$ sudo sh
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
#
```

Compare the output you get to verify that `~/.local/bin` is not included.

Accomplishing what you want to do is best done like this:

```
sudo ~/.local/bin/YourBashScript
```

Technically, you could also change `sudo`'s PATH, but that's probably not your best move.

Comment: What I want is to run the command with `sudo` without any options so I think the best way is to modify `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers` adding the command path